# Yield Only Once Per Iteration

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to do type conversions using a generator, but I want to move to the next element in the iterator once I successfully yield a value. My current attempt will yield multiple values in cases where the expressions are successful:

```
def type_convert(data):
    for item in data:
        try:
            yield int(item)
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as WrongTypeError:
            pass
        try:
            yield float(item)
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as WrongTypeError:
            pass
        yield item
```

How is this accomplished?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something, but what's a case where your cast to `int` will fail but your cast to `float` will succeed?

Comment: @NolenRoyalty -- consider the string: `'1.0'`

Comment: @mgilson that makes perfect sense, thanks :D

Comment: You can either put a `continue` statement after each `yield` statement or nest the try-except clauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to `continue` this loop just like any other:

```
try:
    yield int(item)
    continue
except (ValueError, TypeError) as WrongTypeError:
    pass
```

As a side note, I've always thought `continue` was a strange name for this control structure...

And, here's your corrected code in action:

```
def type_convert(data):
    for item in data:
        try:
            yield int(item)
            continue
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as WrongTypeError:
            pass
        try:
            yield float(item)
            continue
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as WrongTypeError:
            pass
        yield item


for a in type_convert(['a','1','1.0']):
    print (a)
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it does call next() at each try block, but if this is a concern of you, why don't you do

```
try:
  item =  int(item)
except (ValueError, TypeError) as WrongTypeerror
   try:
       item = float(item)
   except (ValueError, TypeError) as WrongTypeError
       pass
yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def type_convert(data):
    for item in data:
        try:
            yield int(item)
            continue
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as WrongTypeError:
            pass
        try:
            yield float(item)
            continue
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as WrongTypeError:
            pass
        yield item
```

This is the result:

```
>>> list(type_convert(["13", 3.5, True]))
[13, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalized answer:

```
def type_convert(*args):
    datatypes = []
    for arg in args:
        if type(arg) == type(type):
            datatypes += [arg]
        else:
            data = arg
    for item in data:
        for datatype in datatypes:
            try:
                yield datatype(item)
                break
            except (ValueError, TypeError) as WrongTypeError:
                pass
        else:
            yield item  # unable to convert to any datatype

for a in type_convert(int, float, ['a','1','1.0']):
    print (a)
```